# "New App Preview" not available in iMovie

Tags: quicktime, imovie

I want to create an App Preview video for an app.  I have started iMovie but no matter what I try the "New App Preview" is greyed out.  I created a movie in Quicktime and imported it in...still nothing.

Comment: Are you following the requirements and steps [according to Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/imovie/)?

Comment: I found the solution.  Open iMovie.  then immediately click "Project" at the top left.  This displays all projects if available.  Then go to File and under that menu option "New App Preview" is active and can be selected.

Comment: What version of iMovie & macOS are you using?

Comment: I found the issue.  I needed to first click "Projects" the immediately under File menu click on New App Preview which is active.

Comment: Great, can you please add that as an Answer and then accept it?  It will help others who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to Open iMovie. then immediately click "Project" at the top left. This displays all projects if available. Then go to File and under that menu option "New App Preview" is active and can be selected

Answer (score 2):

When you first click on iMovie , **don't**  click the "Create New" button right away, instead click "File" in the menu bar then "New App Preview" as shown in pic below:

[image]